# Unable to Open folder using Path after downloading Files(webClient.DownloadFile())

Tags: c#, webclient, smtpclient

Downloading Zip Files using Web client,after downloading files i am sending email notification with downloaded path location.But When click on downloaded path folder should open but its not happening because of Space in download path

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

Code:

```
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(remoteFilePathWithoutQuery);

    string downloadpath =@"C:/Test/RDD Projects/TempProject/"

    webClient.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(remoteFilePath), downloadpath + fileName)
```

if i give (downloadpath  = @"C:/Test/RDD Projects/TempProject/"

able to download files but i am not able to open files from that location.

I tried with Removing space and added %20 (@"C:/Test/RDD%20Projects/TempProject/") files are not downloading

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try use Path.Combine.

```
webClient.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(remoteFilePath),Path.Combine(downloadpath,filename));
```